# Spring can not register spring hateoas resource assembler

Tags: spring, spring-hateoas

I am using spring hateoas in spring and got the problem is spring could not instance hateoas resource assembler , here is my snippet code:

UserHateoasResourceAssembler.java:

```
@Service
public class UserHateoasResourceAssembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<UserDTO, UserHateoasResource> { 

    public UserHateoasResourceAssembler() {
        super(UserController.class, UserHateoasResource.class);
    }


    @Override
    public UserHateoasResource toResource(UserDTO entity) {
        UserHateoasResource resource = createResourceWithId(entity.getId(), entity);                
        return resource;
    }

    @Override
    protected UserHateoasResource instantiateResource(UserDTO entity) {
        return new UserHateoasResource(entity);
    }

}
```

UserController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class UserController {

    @Inject
    private UserHateoasResourceAssembler userAssembler ;

    ....


}
```

The exception was thrown is "No qualifying bean of type [UserHateoasResourceAssembler] found for dependency. I know this root cause is can not create instance of assembler.

I tried to use @Service or @Component but both does not work. I also tried to use @Autowire instead, but did not work too. I have to fix that by adding @Scope( proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS). But I wonder if there is any another solution to resolve it instead of using @Scope ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the elegant solution. Due to my application using generated code and it used @EnableAspectJAutoProxy, this annotation default set auto-proxy = false and using JDK proxy, so almost the instance of class that implementing an interface was not allowed. We have to @inject the interface instead. So to inject the implementation class, have 2 options here:

1. Set @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true )
2. Remove this annotation if we does not really need that.